Create a Google Analytics 4 Query Explorer in my appliation
I'm developing an interface similar to Google Analytics Query Explorer( https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/query-explorer/ ) for my client's Google Analytics data.
My goal is to load all available dimensions and metrics for Google Analytics 4 (GA4) to allow users to explore data effectively.
Can someone help me with the following questions?

Is it possible to create a GA4 Query Explorer within my application?
How can I determine which metrics are supported by which dimensions, and vice versa?

How do I achieve this?
